# How can i refactor these lines of code?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've this condition in my code which have similar code and i believe this can reduce into a much simpler code,

```
$translatedArray['voptions'] = 'test';
$array1 = ['tesst', 'test1'];

if (isset($translatedArray['voptions'])) {
    if (in_array($translatedArray['voptions'], $array1)) {
        functioncall();
    }
} else {
    functioncall();
}
```

I want to reduce these lines of code to a much simpler version or it the else condition could be eliminated that would be great.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if (!isset($translatedArray['voptions']) ||  
    in_array($translatedArray['voptions'], $array1)) {
    functioncall();
}
```